# Logical comparison of two vectors with binary (0/1) result

Tags: r, vector

For an assignment I had to create a random vector theta, a vector p containing for each element of theta the associated probability, and another random vector u. No problems thus far, but I'm stuck with the next instruction which I report below:

Generate a vector r1 that has a 1 in position i if pi ≥ ui and 0 if pi < ui. The
vector r1 is a Rasch item given the latent variable theta.

```
theta=rnorm(1000,0,1)
p=(exp(theta-1))/(1+exp(theta-1))
u=runif(1000,0,1)
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
r1<-for(i in 1:1000){
if(p[i]<u[i]){
  return("0")
} else {
  return("1")}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ifelse](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) function:

```
r1 <- ifelse(p >= u, 1, 0)
```

Or you can simply convert the logical comparison into a numeric vector, which turns `TRUE` into 1 and `FALSE` into 0:

```
r1 <- as.numeric(p >= u)
```

Answer (score 1):

@DavidRobinson gave a nice working solution, but let's look at why your attempt didn't work:

```
r1<-for(i in 1:1000){
if(p[i]<u[i]){
  return("0")
} else {
  return("1")}
}
```

We've got a few problems, biggest of which is that you're confusing `for` loops with general functions, both by assigning and using `return()`. `return()` is used when you are writing your own function, with `function() <- ...`.  Inside a `for` loop it isn't needed. A `for` loop just runs the code inside it a certain number of times, it can't return something like a function.

You *do* need a way to store your results. This is best done by pre-allocating a results vector, and then filling it inside the `for` loop.

```
r1 <- rep(NA, length(p)) # create a vector as long as p
for (i in 1:1000) {
    if (p[i] < u[i]) {   # compare the ith element of p and u
        r1[i] <- 0       # put the answer in the ith element of r1
    } else {
        r1[i] <- 1
    }
}
```

We could simplify this a bit. Rather than bothering with the `if` *and* the `else`, you could start `r1` as all 0's, and then only change it to a 1 if `p[i] >= u[i]`. Just to be safe I think it's better to make the for statement something like `for (i in 1:length(p))`, or best yet `for (i in seq_along(p))`, but the beauty of R is how few for loops are necessary, and @DavidRobinson's vectorized suggestions are far cleaner.